# How to create typography like this?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, typography

I'm wondering how to create this typography in Photoshop or Illustrator
(It's all Travis Kane's posters https://www.instagram.com/ttraviskanee/)
[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create stuff like this in Illustrator [using a blend](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/blending-objects.html)

The example below is just a  very quick example. I'm sure with some time and care you could create something much better.

It's constructed from some sheared text, which has been rotated, and converted to outlines.

I then stacked 3 copies and filled them with different colours - black on the bottom, blue in the middle and red on top, selected them all, and made a step blend (about 300 steps).

You can then bend the spine of the blend using the Anchor Point Tool <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. You can add anchors, and curves as you please just like any Bézier path.

Finally I created a black rectangle and placed it behind everything, and placed a copy of the text on the very top and filled it with a lighter red colour.

Example

[image]

Note: It's probably better to do this with an RGB document and choose RGB colours for the text and background, because CMYK colours don't seem blend so well.